# Trying to get split tunneling working with OpenVPN, using a tutorial, but I'm getting "route-up" exiting with error code 1

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn, transmission

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
[Transmission daemon over OpenVPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583679/transmission-daemon-over-openvpn-on-a-beagleboard-arm-sbc/583680#583680?newreg=1f3c93e1ab224478822c810938b8a2db)

On an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server box, and I cannot get openvpn to start transmission. OpenVPN connects fine, but there is a warning saying that route up could not run, and it exits with a status of 1. I can't seem to find what an error status of 1 even is, to start troubleshooting it. The vpn connects, but it tells me:

```
WARNING: Failed running command (--route-up): external program exited with error status: 1
```

The line right above it says:

```
initctl: Event Failed
```

but it is the exact same file that everyone else is using which seems to run fine. If I run the route-up.sh straight from bash, it gives me the same "Event Failed" with no additional information.

FYI, this is all that is in the route-up.sh file:

```
#! /bin/bash

/sbin/initctl emit transmission-vpn-up VPN_GATEWAY=$route_vpn_gateway LOCAL_IP=$ifconfig_local
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated, as I am lost on what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured out the issue by now, but I had the same problem, so I'll just post what fixed things for me, in case anyone else comes across this.

> I changed the line dev tap to dev tap1, to force the virtual device to be tap1 instead of being assigned by OpenVPN, again because of running a separate OpenVPN server. Even if you're not running a VPN server, this change shouldn't matter. The firewall scripts have been written to use tap1, so if you would rather use another device then remember to change those scripts where appropriate.

I'd missed this bit in the instructions, so I hadn't replaced the occurrences of tap1 in each location. Also, I needed to switch from tap to tun, as I was getting warnings about config differences between the local and the remote (PIA). If you have any other issues, you should be able to get more detailed info in the logs for upstart (/var/log/upstart/).