# VPN Services for Ubuntu in China

Tags: vpn

I'm a student in China and I have recently installed Ubuntu on my PC, but I'm having trouble trying to find a VPN for Linux. The Tor browser is ***way*** too slow (doesn't load at all, only displays title) and HotSpotShield/AstrillVPN/AirVPN requires a premium account. I've made a ProtonVPN account and got a OpenVPN username and password, downloaded a few of Proton's openVPN configuration files, but OpenVPN doesn't want to connect as well. I've also tried NordVPN, but I can't access the nordVPN website or any other VPN website to download it.

Comment: Most of the known VPN servers are probably blocked in China. Not sure there is anything we can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install OpenVPN and then use the profile offered on [here](https://www.openinternetaccess.com). There's no GUI for OpenVPN so you have to keep a terminal open with.

**Extra:** To make sure a particular app runs through the VPN interface and nowhere else, launch it as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37412/how-can-i-ensure-transmission-traffic-uses-a-vpn).

Slight disclaimer: I haven't read their data protection policy and am not affiliated with OIA in any way. Assume your data is invisible to the PRC but fully transparent to the OIA crowd.

Comment: Do I just do `sudo openvpn --config OpenInternetAccess.ovpn`?

Comment: yup, that's it.

Comment: The configuration files work on Windows with the OpenVPN GUI, but when I try them here on my Ubuntu PC it doesn't work at all. I went to google.com and it's just a blank page with no title. Here's the log: https://pastebin.com/4WTT2BMw

Comment: The log looks fine. If you try `ping 8.8.8.8` you should get responses. What's probably (predictably) happening is that the throughput is split among too many peers, since it's a free VPN after all. This means the page loads extra slow.

Comment: I used `nmcli connection import type openvpn file <file.ovpn>` to add the ovpn file, then it appeared in my "top-right-status-menu". I clicked that and it connected

Answer (score 0):

There is a GUI for OpenVPN. You find it in `network-manager-applet` which is in your systray and have to import your configuration file `VPN Connections -> Configure VPN -> + -> Import a saved VPN connection...`
It's build in `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`. If you want to keep sure, that network-manager (nm) add routes with iptables.
If you are not a GNOME user, then you can try nmcli. It's a commando line tool.
`nmcli connection import type openvpn file <file.ovpn>`.