# Can someone explain these rules for a specific user and a VPN in iptables?

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, transmission

I used a script from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37412/how-can-i-ensure-transmission-traffic-uses-a-vpn/960752#960752) to setup rules that make sure user `transmission-daemon` can only send traffic via the VPN i use.

At least that's what the author says. I have troubles understanding the following output. For example, what does the line `tcp spt:9091 owner GID match debian-transmission`  mean? Why is there no traffic on that rule?

Hint: My ethernet port is `enp3s0` (like `eth0`).

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  436 35225 f2b-sshd   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
 1085  221K ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere            
 2913  923K ACCEPT     all  --  enp3s0 any     anywhere             anywhere            
  112 12221 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0            all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4540 packets, 1267K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    enp3s0  anywhere             192.168.100.0/25     tcp spt:9091 owner GID match debian-transmission
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    enp3s0  anywhere             192.168.100.0/25     udp spt:9091 owner GID match debian-transmission
 2263  202K ACCEPT     all  --  any    tun0    anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match debian-transmission
   12  2581 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match debian-transmission
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match debian-transmission reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.100.0/25 -p tcp --sport 9091 -m owner --gid-owner debian-transmission -o enp3s0 -j ACCEPT
```

will ACCEPT the packet ***IF*** it is to any IP in the range 192.168.100.0 - 192.168.100.127 ***AND*** the protocol is tcp ***AND*** the source port is 9091 ***AND*** the packet owner is debian-transmission ***AND*** it is destined for the network interface enp3s0 ***ELSE*** go to the next iptables rule.

Comment: So this means that the VPN could be sending from `127.0.0.1:9091` (which is tun0) to `enp3s0`. Why is there no traffic? Does `tun0` have to send to `enp3s0` to send something out? Also, I wanted to edit your answer (`.1.` to `.100.`), but I have to edit more than 6 characters to be able to save it. :)

Comment: Was able to edit now.

Comment: Ah, `tun0` is actually `10.8.8.9`, so there must be another reason for the rule for `9091`. Probably the web interface (which I don't use).

Comment: So, an important part is the last line `REJECT ... owner GID match debian-transmission reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`: Any packet that did not match the previous rules gets rejected in the output chain if it is send by this specific user. Therefore it is impossible to send any packet to `enp3s0` with that user?

Comment: @Ben You can *send* packets to an interface but they will be rejected, yes.  That restricts the `debian-transmission` user from transmitting to anywhere other than the VPN tunnel, or to the private network on port 9025.