# Auto reconnect to VPN on disconnect?

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-gnome

I'm an Ubuntu GNOME user and I was wondering if there is a way to be able to **automatically reconnect to a VPN on disconnection**. I'm using the **OpenVPN** protocol.

I've checked Network Manager thoroughly but could not find such an option, only to connect to the VPN when connected to a specific WiFi.

Comment: I have this problem and I am not using OpenVPN. It is openconnect and fortisslvpn.

Answer (score 63):

As of 18.10 (cannot check in earlier versions) VPN connections in NetworkManager have a setting `vpn.persistent` which does just that: reconnects to a VPN on connection loss until you disconnect manually. It is set to `"no"` by default and unfortunately isn't exposed neither in Gnome Network Settings nor in nm-connection-editor.

But you can set it through a CLI like this:

```
nmcli connection modify <Your VPN connection name> connection.autoconnect-retries 0
nmcli connection modify <Your VPN connection name> vpn.persistent yes
```

The connection must exist before you do that, of course. And `autoconnect-retries 0` actually means "retry forever".

Also note that these settings get reset occasionally, probably with updates to NetworkManager or related packages, so you need to check them and correct back.

sources:

- https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-connection.html
- https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-vpn.html

Comment: _this_ is what I wanted. Thanks a million

Comment: Since this setting is available, why doesn't network settings show it? And where / how did you find out? There is no mention of this at https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html but since running the command seems to succeed I guess it works...

Comment: @alf I think I found this setting just by poking at nmcli in the terminal, but it's also documented at https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings.html#id-1.2.7.4.41 and in nm-settings man page

Comment: If you have multiple connections, can you use this solution for all of them... assuming that it will recognize the current connection, and not attempt to connect the connections not currently being used?

Comment: Use "nmcli con show" to list VPN names in the terminal (as well as wifi connection names)

Comment: ... and `nmcli connection show <Connection Name>` to show all the settings/details of the connection

Comment: Probably it's out of scope of the answer, but `vpn.persistent yes` doesn't reconnect when you re-login in the system (e. g. open your laptop back)

Comment: On 22.04 at least, I also needed `connection.autoconnect yes`.

Comment: comment about `connection.autoconnect yes` seems incorrect per `man nm-settings-nmcli` documentation (or [online](https://www.networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/nm-settings-nmcli.html)). I say this because the entry for `connection.autoconnect` specifically mentions "Note that autoconnect is not implemented for VPN profiles. See "secondaries" as an alternative to automatically connect VPN profiles." - AFAIU `secondaries` is more for initial auto-connect after log into Linux session (at least thats how I use it). Also `vpn.persistent` still exists with no plans to deprecate as of nmcli v1.42.8

Answer (score 22):

OpenVPN has a build-in mechanism to automatically detect dead links and reconnect. In Network Manager go to "Edit Connections", select your VPN connection and choose "Edit". In the "VPN" tab click on "Advanced..." and go to the "General" Tab. There you have two relevant options:

"Specify ping interval" tell OpenVPN how frequently to check if the link is still alive. "Specify exit or restart ping" tells it how long to wait until it takes action and which action to take.

Example: My setting are "30 / ping-restart / 300". This means OpenVPN checks every 30 seconds if the link is still active. If the link is down for 300 seconds it initiates a restart.

This way there is no need for external scripts...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is not true for Ubuntu 18.04 at least. I have ping interval and ping-restart but it will disable itself anyway.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: the answer by m0NKey bR4in seems to work (setting `vpn.persistent` to `yes`).

Comment: How do you do this without the GUI?

Comment: @Rolf Add an entry `keepalive <Interval> <Timeout>` to your OpenVPN conf. This will ping the peer all <Interval> seconds and restart the connection after the <Timeout> expires without getting a reply.

Comment: As of 22.04 Network Manager still kills the VPN and the `nmcli` commands are needed.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging I found [this answer](http://www.gabsoftware.com/tips/automatically-reconnect-to-your-vpn-on-linux/comment-page-1/#comment-56778), tested it (on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04) and so far it seems working.

The only thing I might add is that once the script file is created it doesn't necessarily need to be saved to your /home folder. You can save it anywhere, make it executable and add it to the list of startup programs.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:**
None of these answers worked.  I switched to wireguard (https://www.wireguard.com/install/)

```
sudo apt install wireguard
```

And then followed the wireguard setup from my VPN provider.

**Details:**

This issue was happening for me on Ubuntu 20.04.  I tried the top two answers under this question (MonkeyBrain: https://askubuntu.com/a/1103326/327631 and OttoEisen: https://askubuntu.com/a/779391/327631), separately and together and the issue still occurred.

After using `sudo grep openvpn /var/log/syslog` I saw:

```
Mar  9 01:36:06 **** nm-openvpn[429236]: [vpn-ch5] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Mar  9 01:36:06 **** nm-openvpn[429236]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Mar  9 01:36:11 **** nm-openvpn[429236]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
...
Mar  9 01:36:31 **** nm-openvpn[429236]: Server poll timeout, restarting
Mar  9 01:36:31 **** nm-openvpn[429236]: SIGUSR1[soft,server_poll] received, process restarting
...
Mar  9 01:36:46 **** nm-openvpn[429236]: WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): could not execute external program
Mar  9 01:36:46 **** nm-openvpn[429236]: Exiting due to fatal error
```

And some of those logs led to this answer which also did not fix the issue:

https://askubuntu.com/a/906055/327631

Finally found this from my VPN provider, which also did not solve the problem!

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/openvpn/scripts 

sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved/master/update-systemd-resolved -P /etc/openvpn/scripts/ 

sudo chmod +x /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
```

Then edit your OpenVPN client file (e.g. *.ovpn) by adding the up/down scripts.
Add these 3 lines after the line where it shows your server name (e.g. remote servername.vpn.com 443 TCP):

```
script-security 2 
up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved 
down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
```

So I gave up and switched to wireguard (https://www.wireguard.com/install/)

```
sudo apt install wireguard
```

And then followed the wireguard setup from my VPN provider.

Answer (score 0):

After claiming it was a SMOP (Simple Matter of Programming), I wrote a bash script that monitors for "Link Down", then executes a user script. Less CPU usage, more responsive than the `while true....sleep 30` method. See my answer at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665721/how-to-rotate-wifi-connections). It's about "rotating WiFi connections", but will probably work for you, too

Answer (score 0):

this script will work on 16.04 where `nmcli con status` no longer works:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
CON="purple"
STATUS=`nmcli con show --active | grep purple | cut -f1 -d " "`
if [ -z "$STATUS" ]; then
    nmcli con up $CON
fi
```

Comment: A bit shorter `STATUS="$(nmcli con show -f name | grep purple)"`. Or you can simply check if the actual connection is active by doing `nmcli con show --active id 'purple'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the complete answer based on other answers goes as follow :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash +x
  while [ "true" ]
   do
        CON="Your-VPN-Name"
        STATUS=`nmcli con show --active | grep $CON | cut -f1 -d " "`
        if [ -z "$STATUS" ]; then
                echo "Disconnected, trying to reconnect..."
                (sleep 1s && nmcli con up $CON)
        else
                echo "Already connected !"
        fi
        sleep 30
   done
```